# Why is Java 8 Instant.now() showing the wrong UTC on my local server?

Tags: java, time, server, utc, java.time.instant

Java8 `Instant.now()` gives the current time already formatted in UTC. I created a simple sandbox test on [CompileJava.net](https://www.compilejava.net/) to verify my intented results:

```
Timestamp createdDateUtc = Timestamp.from(Instant.now());
System.out.println(createdDateUtc);

LocalDateTime databaseUtcLocal = createdDateUtc.toLocalDateTime();
ZonedDateTime databaseUtcZoned = databaseUtcLocal.atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC"));
ZonedDateTime userTimezoneTime = databaseUtcZoned.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("Asia/Qatar")); 
System.out.println(userTimezoneTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a")));
```

*Note: it is currently 11:16 AM UTC on 12/01/2018.*

When I run this code on the online compiler, I get the output:

```
2018-12-01 11:17:43.637
12/01/2018 02:17:43 PM
```

But when I run this code on my local JBOSS server, I get this output instead:

```
2018-12-01 03:18:07.464
12/01/2018 06:18:07 AM
```

What could be going wrong here? Is my server UTC clock incorrect? My local server's physical location is in California. While that shouldn't matter, it does seem odd that when I'm trying to display the UTC time using `Instant.now()` I get Pacific Time instead.

Any help much appreciated!

**UPDATE**

As pointed out by the accepted answer, the issue was my `Timestamp.from()` method:

```
System.out.println(Instant.now());
System.out.println(Timestamp.from(Instant.now()));
```

Output:

```
2018-12-01T11:48:33.153Z
2018-12-01 03:48:33.171
```

So now my issue has changed. If you have a similar issue, I found my answer on this Stack Overflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43837323/how-do-i-make-java-sql-timestamp-utc-time). Instead of `Timestamp.from(Instant.now())` I used this ugly mess:

```
Timestamp.valueOf(ZonedDateTime.of(LocalDateTime.now(), ZoneId.systemDefault()).withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("UTC")).toLocalDateTime())
```

Comment: The `Timestamp` class has design ptoblems and is long outdated. And you have nothing to use it for here. For the simple way of converting from UTC to a specific time zone see for example [Java 8 – Convert Instant to ZonedDateTime](https://www.mkyong.com/java8/java-8-convert-instant-to-zoneddatetime/). Or to obtain the current time in a time zone, just use `ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Asia/Qatar"))`.

Comment: The issue in not only with `Timestamp.from()`, but with all of the `Timestamp` class. Avoid it. If you thought you needed a `Timestamp` for your database, you probably don’t. A not too outdated JDBC driver should accept either an `Instant`, an `OFfsetDateTime` or a `LocalDateTime`. Try for example `yourPreparedStatement.setObject(6. Instant.now())` or `yourPreparedStatement.setObject(6. OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC))`..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think there is a problem in `Timestamp.toString()` method. If you will look inside it you will see:

```
public String toString () {

    int year = super.getYear() + 1900;
    int month = super.getMonth() + 1;
    int day = super.getDate();
    int hour = super.getHours();
    int minute = super.getMinutes();
    int second = super.getSeconds();
    // other code
}
```

Methods `getHours()`, `getMinutes()` and other are from `Date` class and based on documentation they interpret it by local timezone [Date.getHours()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getHours--).