# Spark using timestamp inside a RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, timezone, rdd, unix-timestamp

I'm trying to compare timestamps within a map, but Spark seems to be using a different timezone or something else that is really weird. 
I read a dummy csv file like the following to build the input dataframe :

```
"ts"
"1970-01-01 00:00:00"
"1970-01-01 00:00:00"
```

```
df.show(2)
+-------------------+
|        ts         |
+-------------------+
|1970-01-01 00:00:00|
|1970-01-01 00:00:00|
+-------------------+
```

For now, nothing to report, but then :

```
df.rdd.map { row =>
  val timestamp = row.getTimestamp(0)
  val timestampMilli = timestamp.toInstant.toEpochMilli
  val epoch = Timestamp.from(Instant.EPOCH)
  val epochMilli = epoch.toInstant.toEpochMilli
  (timestamp, timestampMilli, epoch, epochMilli)
}.foreach(println)
```

```
(1970-01-01 00:00:00.0,-3600000,1970-01-01 01:00:00.0,0)
(1970-01-01 00:00:00.0,-3600000,1970-01-01 01:00:00.0,0)
```

I don't understand why both timestamp are not `1970-01-01 00:00:00.0, 0`. Anyone know what I'm missing ?

NB : I already [setup the session timezone to UTC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48767008/spark-strutured-streaming-automatically-converts-timestamp-to-local-time), using the following properties.

```
spark.sql.session.timeZone=UTC
user.timezone=UTC
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `java.sql.Timestamp` class inherits from `java.util.Date`.  They both have the behavior of *storing* a UTC-based numeric timestamp, but *displaying* time in the local time zone.  You'd see this with `.toString()` in Java, the same as you're seeing with `println` in the code given.

I believe your OS (or environment) is set to something similar to `Europe/London`.  Keep in mind that at the Unix epoch (`1970-01-01T00:00:00Z`), [London was on BST](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/uk/london?year=1970) (UTC+1).

Your `timestampMilli` variable is showing `-3600000` because it's interpreted your input in local time as `1970-01-01T00:00:00+01:00`, which is equivalent to `1969-12-31T23:00:00Z`.

Your `epoch` variable is showing `1970-01-01 01:00:00.0` because `0` is equivalent to `1970-01-01T00:00:00Z`, which is equivalent to `1970-01-01T01:00:00+01:00`.

See also:

- [Is java.sql.Timestamp timezone specific?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14070572/is-java-sql-timestamp-timezone-specific)
- [How do I make java.sql.Timestamp UTC time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43837323/how-do-i-make-java-sql-timestamp-utc-time)
- [Java - Convert java.time.Instant to java.sql.Timestamp without Zone offset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42766674/java-convert-java-time-instant-to-java-sql-timestamp-without-zone-offset)

I do see you noted you set your session time zone to UTC, which in theory should work. But clearly the results are showing that it isn't using that.  Sorry, but I don't know Spark well enough to tell you why.  But I would focus on that part of the problem.

Comment: Better cast `Timestamp` to `Long`, but be carefull Spark is handling epoch in seconds (not millis)
`df.select(col("ts").cast(LongType)).rdd.map { row => val timestamp = row.getLong(0) }`