# How to generate a java.sql.Timestamp in UTC for a query comparison?

Tags: java, datetime, jdbc, spring-data-jpa, spring-jdbc

I'm currently building a gateway using Spring-Boot that reads data from a PSQL database. The PSQL database `v11.3` is populated by a Rails web app, running Rails `5.1.3`. The Spring app is using `Java 8` and Spring Data JPA.

The relevant query is run by a scheduled method in the Spring app, that compares the current time against the `updated_at` times of the table. The query is as follows:

```
@Query("SELECT d from SimulatedDeviceEntity d WHERE d.updatedAt > :currentTime")
List<SimulatedDeviceEntity> findByLastUpdated(@Param("currentTime") Timestamp currentTime);
```

If I retrieve a `SimulatedDeviceEntity` from this query and get its time from `getUpdatedAt`, it is of type `java.sql.Timestamp`. When displayed using `toString()` I get `2019-06-26 17:24:20.034923` for the device that was updated in my local time at `13:24`.

I've tried a variety of answers on how to generate a Timestamp in UTC, including [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43837323/how-do-i-make-java-sql-timestamp-utc-time) where my code to create the Timestamp is

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.now();
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of(ldt, ZoneId.of("GMT"));
Timestamp currentTime = Timestamp.valueOf(zdt.toLocalDateTime());
```

Regardless of what I try, calling `toString` on any of these will generate the Timestamp in my local time, which is 4 hours behind UTC. I've come to understand that this is intentional, however when calling `toString` on the Timestamps retrieved from the Rails app, even then they display in UTC.
Given that `toString` should display the Timestamp in local time, the fact that it displays for my `last_updated` times in UTC leads me to believe something else is at play here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java SQL Timestamp to ZonedDateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52943309/java-sql-timestamp-to-zoneddatetime) (unanswered, though). See also [Java - Convert java.time.Instant to java.sql.Timestamp without Zone offset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42766674/java-convert-java-time-instant-to-java-sql-timestamp-without-zone-offset). And don’t use `Timestamp`. Spring JPA should be able to handle either an `Instant`, an `OffsetDateTime` or a `LocalDateTIme`.

Comment: Thanks for the info Ole. I arrived at `Timestamp` due to the `updated_at` value automatically being cast to it, ie:

`Date updatedAt = device.getUpdatedAt();`
`logger.info("updatedAt class: " + updatedAt.getClass()); -> java.sql.Timestamp`
Noted, I will try another type for this.

Answer (score 0):

Actually when you comparing two Timestamps you don't need to convert them o the same timezone. It is smart enough to compare them as absolute times. What it does it converts any `Timestamp` to a `Long` value of milliseconds that have passed since 1.1.1970 00:00 UTC, and then compares them. So you probably do not need to convert your time. it should work as it is.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Michael, it definitely seems as though it should work. For whatever reason, it still appears to be adding those 4 hours to the timestamps of `updated_at`. This might be a conversion issue as those are originally of Ruby type `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone` and they're getting cast into Timestamps when retrieved in the Spring app. Perhaps there could be a translational issue where the UTC vs Local time offset is literally being imbedded into the `Long` value of the time?

Comment: Check the Locale and timezone set for your DB see if the time written in DB is correct. That might give you a hint

Comment: FWIW, I've read that Java stores ALL date/time related data as long values in UTC.  The usual confusion arises from the fact that Java is also "locale aware" and always "prints" date/time related data in LOCAL (per the JVM) time zone.  The only way around this is to use, for example, SimpleDateFormat to configure which time zone to "print" in/from.

Comment: I update the timezone of my PSQL db to UTC and that didn't do the trick either. Will keep digging.